# Creating a new data entry into a database with eloquent and trying to access the variable in the url

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to access a variable passed in the url to pass on to a new form.
I currently have a clients table which has a hasMany relationship with a Lifepolicy table. When building the create form for the life policy I keep getting undefined variable. (Using Laravel 5.8)

Here's my code:

```
class Lifepolicy extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [
        'id'
    ];

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }

    public function addLifepolicy($lifepolicy)
    {
        $this->lifepolicies()->create($lifepolicy);
    }
}

class Client extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [
        'id'
    ];

    public function Lifepolicy()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Lifepolicy::class);
    }
}

     public function create(Request $request, Client $client)
    {

        return view('lifepolicies.create', $client);
    }

    Route::resource('/client/{client}/lifepolicy', 'ClientLifepolicyController');
```

and this it the part which is throwing up the error:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="/client/{{ $client->id }}/lifepolicy">
```

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
public function create(Request $request, Client $client)
{
    return view('lifepolicies.create', compact('client'));

}
```